# Resize animation from the center on a hover with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have this animation and on the hover the size on my span is bigger. But i would like that the animation beginning from the center of the mouse, it works well with Safari and Google Chrome but not Mozilla Firefox (50.1.0).

Why ?

**https://jsfiddle.net/9rrbzwem/11/**

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("span").css({
    left: e.pageX - 50,
    top: e.pageY - 50
  });
});

$("div").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 0);
  $("span").stop().animate({
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    margin: 0 // changed
  }, 200);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
  $("span").stop().animate({
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    margin: 50 // changed
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: I put this in a local file and it worked just like in Chrome/Safari (I'm on a Mac). But when it's a jsFiddle, the issue you describe happens. I also tried a codepen, and no issues on the three browsers mentioned above. http://codepen.io/alexwc_/pen/QGXwda

Comment: Ok, the problem that was my Jquery was too old (1.7.0), I put the newest version (3.1.0) and know it works on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transform to position span element.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("span").css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});

$("div").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 0);

}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
div:hover span {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   -moz-transform-origin: center;
   -webkit-transform-origin: center;
   transform-origin: center;
}
span {
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition:  width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  
  -webkit-transition:  width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  
  transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gt73k2ox/